# How to change System of Measurements on a Legacy Form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following form:

[image]

Right now, all values are entered using English system of measurements.  I need to allow entry of Metric values as well.

Here is what I am thinking:

- add a drop-down `system unit select box` for English/Metric
- Depending on the state of `system unit select box`, change the names of physical properties (gpm, psi, etc)

**Question:**

So let's say I add a select box for English/Metric.  How do I read the state of that box and how do I implement the label-changing from English to Metric system?  i.e. `gpm` -> `m3h` (meter cubed per hour), etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <select name="unit_system" id="unit_system">
        <option value="English">English</option>
        <option value="Metric">Metric</option>      
    </select>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#unit_system").change(function() {
            if ($('#unit_system').val() == "English")
            {
                $('.input_gpm').html('gpm');
            }
            else if ($('#unit_system').val() == "Metric")
            {
                $('.input_gpm').html('m3h');
            }   
        });
    </script>

    <td class="input_gpm"><b>gpm</b></td>
```